# Python parse XML to HTML : can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

I'm Python beginner and I'm doing a programs to parse XML file to HTML file. The file is about student record and have to calculate the overall score and I have trouble to make function for it. This is the first time i make question so sorry if I do incorrect format.

```
    def overallScore(Weights,studentScore):
         totalScore = 0
         totalWeight = 0
         for i in range(0,len(Weights)):
            Weights[i] = float(Weights[i])
            totalScore = totalScore + studentScore[i]*Weights[i]
            totalWeight = totalWeight + Weights[i]
         overall = totalScore/totalWeight
         overall = "%.2f" % overall
         overallString = '    <p class="overall">Overall : ' + overall + '</p>\n'
         return overallString
    import xml.sax
    def characters(self,data):
        if (self.inRecords):
            if (self.inStudents):
                if (self.inStudent):
                    if(self.inName):
                        self.studentNames.append(data.strip())
                    elif (self.inUsername):
                        self.studentUser.append(data.strip())
                    elif (self.inScores):
                        self.studentScore.append(data.strip().split(","))
            if (self.inCourse):
                if (self.inTitles):
                    self.Titles = data.strip().split(",")
                elif (self.inWeights):
                    self.Weights = data.strip().split(",")

self.outfile.write(overallScore(self.Weights,self.studentScore))
```

When i run the program i got this error message :

```
totalScore = totalScore + studentScore[i]*Weights[i]
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

i try to convert it to int or float but all of them not working.
here is xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<records>
  <students>
    <student>
      <name>Sergey Brin</name>
      <username>brinsergey</username>
      <scores>0.0,90.0,95.0,94.0,0.0,99.0,92.0</scores>
    </student>
    <student>
      <name>Steve Wosniak</name>
      <username>signedbywoz</username>
      <scores>85.0,93.0,98.0,96.0,98.0,100.0,100.0</scores>
    </student>
  </students>
  <course>
    <titles>lab1,lab2,hw1,exam1,lab3,hw2,exam2</titles>
    <weights>3.0,3.0,4.0,6.0,3.0,4.0,10.0</weights>
  </course>
</records>
```

Answer (score 0):

`studentScore[i]` is a `list` or `tuple`, while `Weights[i]` is a `float`; as the error says, you can't multiply a `list` nor a `tuple` by a `float`.

Try putting in a `print(studentScore)` at the top of `overallScore` so you can see exactly what it is.